# Problema recorrido ResulSet Java SQL SERVER

Tags: java, sql-server

Estoy tratando de obtener valores de un procedimiento almacenado

el problema que presento es que el ResulSet me da el siguiente error:

"**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: El nombre de columna ope_num no es válido**"

```
public List<ConsultaOperaciones> consultaOpe(int cli_rut){
    ArrayList<ConsultaOperaciones> ListaConsulta = new ArrayList<ConsultaOperaciones>();

    try {

        Connection conexion = dataSource.getConnection();
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        String sql = "exec sp_opercliente ?";
        cs = conexion.prepareCall(sql);
        cs.setInt(1, cli_rut);
        ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){

            ConsultaOperaciones consultaOperaciones = new ConsultaOperaciones();

            consultaOperaciones.setCli_razon(rs.getString("cli_razon"));
            consultaOperaciones.setOpe_num(rs.getInt("ope_num"));

            ListaConsulta.add(consultaOperaciones);     
        }
```

Lo que veo que el procedimiento retorna como respuesta 4 tablas, pero la columna "ope_num" no esta en la primera tabla, y unicamenete me esta capturando columnas que están en la primera tabla si no pertenecen a la primera me arroja la excepción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay algo que pueda hacer para que el ResultSet lea los datos de las otras Tablas?

Saludos

Comment: Dado que estarías recibiendo varios `ResultSet` (las diferentes tablas), tendrías que hacer uso de `getResultSet()` para obtener la que te interesa o leerlas todas en bucle si fuera preciso. [Revisa la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/jdbc/using-multiple-result-sets?view=sql-server-ver15) y los ejemplos que hay allí, te darán una idea de lo que debes hacer.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ciertamente con esto puedo ver el segundo ResultSet pero no me deja tomar valores del tercero ni ve el ultimo, estoy tratando de implementarlo

Answer (score 0):

```
// Recuperalos con un DataAdapter eso te traer todo el dataSet 
// si pones un breakpoint en Fil() verás las 4 DataTables para trabajar con ellas
SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conexion);
connection.Open();
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, estoy tratando de implementar este codigo pero no puedo importar myDataAparter

Comment: lo que entiendo es que la clase SqlDataAdapter es de C# estoy buscando el equivalente en JAVA

Answer (score 0):

Al tratar de implememntar me da este problema, no tengo de donde importar ninguna de esas clases

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

saludos

Comment: Actualicé el código hay que inicializar un objeto de SqlDataAdapter y el conexion donde se encuentra la cadena de conexión a tu base de datos